# response deserialize using json.net returns null

Tags: serialization, null

I have the following json:

```
{
  "13377": {
    "id": 13377,
    "orderId": 13377,
    "executionStatus": "-1",
    "comment": "",
    "htmlComment": "",
    "cycleId": -1,
    "cycleName": "Ad hoc",
    "versionId": 10001,
    "versionName": "Version2",
    "projectId": 10000,
    "createdBy": "vm_admin",
    "modifiedBy": "vm_admin",
    "assignedTo": "user1",
    "assignedToDisplay": "user1",
    "assignedToUserName": "user1",
    "assigneeType": "assignee",
    "issueId": 10013,
    "issueKey": "SAM-14",
    "summary": "Test",
    "label": "",
    "component": "",
    "projectKey": "SAM",
    "folderId": 233,
    "folderName": "testfolder"
  }
}
```

I create the following classes using json2csharp and get:

```
public class __invalid_type__13377
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int orderId { get; set; }
    public string executionStatus { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public string htmlComment { get; set; }
    public int cycleId { get; set; }
    public string cycleName { get; set; }
    public int versionId { get; set; }
    public string versionName { get; set; }
    public int projectId { get; set; }
    public string createdBy { get; set; }
    public string modifiedBy { get; set; }
    public string assignedTo { get; set; }
    public string assignedToDisplay { get; set; }
    public string assignedToUserName { get; set; }
    public string assigneeType { get; set; }
    public int issueId { get; set; }
    public string issueKey { get; set; }
    public string summary { get; set; }
    public string label { get; set; }
    public string component { get; set; }
    public string projectKey { get; set; }
    public int folderId { get; set; }
    public string folderName { get; set; }
}

  public class RootObject
   {
       public __invalid_type__13377 __invalid_name__13377 { get; set; }
   }
```

When I deserialize in C# I receive no error but I get null?

Not sure how to approach this..any suggestions would be welcome.

thankyou.

Comment: Can you show us the code for when the deserializing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your Json object can be deserialized with an Dictionary. On this case, you can build your DataObject like you are doing:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int orderId { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

And Deserialize to

```
Dictionary<string, Foo>
```

If you are using Newtonsoft:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,Foo>(json);
```

You can use sometimes, when the type of object is unknown, the dynamic keyword:

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
```